# Multiple arguments in mongodb aggregate

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mean-stack

I'm trying to get multiple arguments in my mongodb, My code here gets the distinct values for date and count it, but how can I add another argument to get for example another set of distinct and count.

**Example:**

**Here is the output of my code:**

```
[ { _id: '05-09-2019', count3: 1 },
  { _id: '06-09-2019', count3: 1 },
  { _id: '06-21-2019', count3: 1 },
  { _id: '06-30-2019', count3: 5 },]
```

**How can I achieve this:**

```
[ { _id: '05-09-2019', count: 1,  branch: America, count2: 1},
  { _id: '06-09-2019', count: 1,  branch: Germany,count2: 1},
  { _id: '06-21-2019', count: 1,  branch: Philippines,count2: 1},
  { _id: '06-30-2019', count: 5 , branch: Vietnam,count2: 1},]
```

**Here is my code to get the distinct values of date while counting it:**

```
router.get('/blooddonationarea', function(req, res) {
        Blooddonation.aggregate([{$group: {_id : "$date" , count :{$sum:1}}},{$sort: {_id: 1}}],function(err, date) {     
        res.json({ success: true, date: date });
        //console.log(date);
        });  

    });
```

I tried inserting this after the [] clause but it doesn't get the values at all

```
[{ $match: { branch: { $eq: 'Rizal' } } },{$group: {_id : "$date" , count2 :{$sum:1}}},{$sort: {_id: 1}}]
```

**Here is the sample document:**

```
_id:5c1f47dd59cdd931f4ce98ae
blood_product_donated:"Whole Blood"
branch:"Rizal"
deferral_type:"permanent"
date:"10-22-2019"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could start with grouping the documents by both the date and branch keys, then a further pipeline step where you only group by the
date key on the documents from the previous pipeline. Following this example will give you the desired result:

```
router.get('/blooddonationarea', (req, res) => {
    Blooddonation.aggregate([
        { '$group': {
            '_id': { 'date': '$date', 'branch': '$branch' },
            'count': { '$sum': 1 }
        } },
        { '$group': {
            '_id': '$_id.date',
            'count': { '$sum': '$count' },
            'branch': { '$first': '$_id.branch' },
            'count2': { '$first': '$count' } 
        } },
        { '$sort': { '_id': 1 } }
    ], (err, date) => {
        console.log(date);
        if (err) throw err
        res.json({ success: true, date });
    });
});
```